# How does the nose wheel tire stop rotating on retraction as the aircraft takes off?

Tags: aircraft-systems, landing-gear

As we know, the nose wheel tire and main gear tires are rotating when aircraft is taking off and the wheels are retracting. Thus there should be a mechanism to stop this rotation in order to prevent oscillations transmitting to fuselage and damages to wheel well so auto brake system is used in main landing gear brake system to counter this problem. What mechanism used to stop rotation the nose wheel tire? Is it a shoe brake system?

Comment: Since the question references the nose wheel specifically, this is not an exact duplicate of the linked question. The answer is that there are brakes in the form a pads attached to ceiling or front wall of the wheel well. From the 757 AMM "Two wheel spin brakes, attached to the nose wheel well ceiling, stop the nose wheels from spinning after takeoff and gear retraction. The brake pads are installed on the contact surfaces of the spin brakes to provide good frictional contact."

Comment: @SportsRacer: Good comment, voting to reopen, so that you can provide a complete answer.

Comment: Voting to leave closed. The other question covers both main and nose gear, and DeltaLima's answer to it already mentions the pads in the nose wheel well. If Sports Racer wishes to post an answer, s/he can do it there.